# I can't implement ui schema

Tags: json, reactjs, jsonschema

In react app I need to implement ui schema.
The scheme storages in database and react app take it from there and then put it
to Form from react-jsonschema-form package, but textfield doesn't change, it's still "input" but not "textarea".

I use

```
"_uiSchema" : {
    "content" : {
            "items" : {
                "text" : {
                    "ui:widget" : "textarea"
                }
            }
        }
},
```

but text didnt chage type. And text is

```
    "text" : {
    "type" : "string"
},
```

And full Schema

```
{
    "title" : "Career",
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "_id" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "title" : "_id"
        },
        "urlPage" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "title" : "url"
        },
        "subUrls" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "title" : "Sub urls",
            "items" : {
                "type" : "string"
            }
        },
        "content" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "title" : "page",
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "title" : "content",
                    "type" : "object",
                    "properties" : {
                        "categoryTitle" : {
                            "type" : "string",
                            "title" : "Category title"
                        },
                        "popUp" : {
                            "type" : "object",
                            "properties" : {
                                "successSubTitle" : {
                                    "type" : "string"
                                },
                                "successTitle" : {
                                    "type" : "string"
                                },
                                "subTitlePopUp" : {
                                    "type" : "string"
                                },
                                "titlePopUp" : {
                                    "type" : "string"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "categorySubTitle" : {
                            "type" : "string",
                            "title" : "Category sub title"
                        },
                        "tabs" : {
                            "type" : "array",
                            "title" : "Tabs",
                            "items" : {
                                "type" : "object",
                                "properties" : {
                                    "path" : {
                                        "type" : "string"
                                    },
                                    "title" : {
                                        "type" : "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "notFindMessage" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                        },
                        "data" : {
                            "title" : "Open positions",
                            "type" : "array",
                            "items" : {
                                "type" : "object",
                                "properties" : {
                                    "category" : {
                                        "type" : "string"
                                    },
                                    "summary" : {
                                        "type" : "string"
                                    },
                                    "details" : {
                                        "type" : "array",
                                        "items" : {
                                            "type" : "object",
                                            "properties" : {
                                                "sectionTitle" : {
                                                    "type" : "string"
                                                },
                                                //here is my text field
                                                "text" : {  
                                                    "type" : "string"
                                                },
                                                "listItems" : {
                                                    "type" : "array",
                                                    "items" : {
                                                        "type" : "string"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I read guide on te github (https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form#the-uischema-object)

UPDATE

ui schema that works

```
"content" : {
        "items" : {
            "data" : {
                "items" : {
                    "details" : {
                        "items" : {
                            "myText" : {
                                "ui:widget" : "textarea"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the source code of this library and seems like you have to have `description` for items in uiSchema.

```
  "_uiSchema" : {
      "content" : {
              "items" : {
                  "description" : {
                      "ui:widget" : "textarea"
                  }
              }
          }
  }
```

Comment: Did you forget the "text"?

Comment: It will help if you could provide more code regarding you _uiSchema, because as I assumed you post just a part of it

Comment: Its all ui schema. And I did it, Im editing my question